# How can I write gujarati in LaTeX?

Tags: fonts

I am using WinEdt as text editor. I want to write `gujarati` in LaTeX. Please guide me to how can I prepare a `.tex` document to write `gujarati`.

Comment: Does the link provided by @perror help you?